# Changing User - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, wordpress, root, chown

I installed mariadb, nginx, php7.2-fpm, ufw, fail2ban, zip and unzip as a **root** in the past. My site is **WordPress**.

Now I have added an user with root privilages into my server. I won't use root user anymore for security reason.

1. I changed **user:www-data;** to **user:newuser;** in the nginx.conf
2. I run below command to change /var/www chown value

   ```
   chown -R **newuser:newuser** /var/www/
   ```
3. I changed php-fpm user values:

   ```
   user = newuser
   group = newuser
   listen.owner = newuser
   listen.group = newuser
   ```
4. I changed **PermitRootLogin no** and restart **SSH**

**My questions are:**

- Should I change anything in mariadb or etc?
- chown values of /var/log folder **still looks www:data**. Should I change it?
- Should I migrate **Cloudflare SSL** from /etc folder to /home/newuser folder? Because nginx may not see that SSL?

Anything you recommend additionally? Thank you! :)

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: For the first two questions, the answer is "no". For the last, if Nginx can operate normally when keeping SSL files in /etc/, then don't migrate them to any other folder.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu Thank you so much! I really appreciate it :)