# Using root User

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, security, root

I installed WordPress with LEMP on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm using root account.

So using root user can create security issues for LEMP? Should I restore my instance and install again with different user?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root.

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you but how can I migrate all applications to the non-root user?
Could you please help me: https://serverfault.com/questions/957768/changing-user-ubuntu-18-04-lts

Comment: That's very difficult to answer. It depends on what you did to install things. It may be as simple as `chown`ing the WordPress files to another user. It may be more complicated than that.

Comment: "Should I restore my instance and install again with different user?" No need to. For WordPress, changing permission of the application files would be enough as you did with your other question at https://serverfault.com/q/957768/102173 .